# PeoplePicker always inserts 1st person selected instead of array of each person selected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, people-picker

I'm trying build an array named visitorsIDs[] to get the values for a PeoplePicker in SharePoint API, but no matter who I pick in the peoplePicker, the id's that are sent are **always** the id's of the 1st person selected in the people picker.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help/suggestions...

```
function resolvePeoplePickers() {


var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePicker_TopSpan;

this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePicker_TopSpan.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {

// Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                for (var userProperty in user) {
                    userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
                }
            }
            debugger;

            var userloginbase = users[0].Key;
            var userlogin = userloginbase.split("\\");

            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var newUser = context.get_web().ensureUser(xxxxxxx\\' + userlogin[1]);
            context.load(newUser);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                //alert(newUser.get_title());
            },

                function (sender, args) {
                    //alert(args.get_message());
                });
                // pause for a second to let the async ensure user complete.
                setTimeout(function() {


                    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

                        getAssignedToUserIdByEmail(users[0].EntityData.Email);

                        visitorIDs.push(ResolvedToUser.Id);

                    }

                }, 100);

        };
```

Adding this after my original post:

```
function getAssignedToUserIdByEmail(email) {

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/siteusers/getByEmail(%27' + encodeURIComponent(email) +  '%27)',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: (function (data) {
                debugger;
                if (data.d && data.d.LoginName) {
                    //alert(data.d.Id);
                    ResolvedToUser = data.d;
                }
            }),
            error: (function (e) {
                alert("Something wrong happened. ");
            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: In this line "visitorIDs.push(ResolvedToUser.Id);". What is ResolveToUser? Where is that getting set?

Comment: @RayHogan  Hi.  I added a  function to my original post just now.  It shows  ResolvedToUser = data.d;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing this line from:

```
getAssignedToUserIdByEmail(users[0].EntityData.Email);
```

to

```
getAssignedToUserIdByEmail(users[i].EntityData.Email);
```

It looks like it is hardcoded to pass in the first element instead of using **i** to resolve each user in the loop.